# Spring Data Elasticsearch - how to pause refresh?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch

Spring Data Elasticsearch version: 3.2.6.RELEASE

I am implementating a bulk index mechanism and would like to pause refreshing of the index whilst the bulk index is taking place.

Apparently it used to be possible to do the following:

```
@Override
public void bulkIndex(@NonNull List<T> entities, @NonNull String index) {
    elasticsearchTemplate.refresh(index, false);

    // perform bulk index...

    elasticsearchTemplate.refresh(index, true);
}
```

Now the library only seems to allow this call `elasticsearchTemplate.refresh(index);`.

What is the new way of stopping and starting an index refresh using Spring Data Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by calling bulkIndex with Refresh Policy....

Try with this:

```
BulkOptions bulkOptions = BulkOptions.builder().withRefreshPolicy(WriteRequest.RefreshPolicy.NONE).build();
elasticsearchTemplate.bulkIndex(listOfIndex, bulkOptions);
```